# Why progressive migration to next.js 13 fails for pages inside the app directory?

Tags: next.js

I have a next.js 12 website that I intend to progressively upgrade to next.js 13.

I updated to the `next@latest` which is `13.0.0` and I also updated react which is `18.2.0` at the time.

Then I ran `npm run dev` and everything worked just fine.

Now I added an `app` directory, and inside it I added another directory for my page called `test` for `/test` route, and I added a file in it called `page.js` that is a simple page.

However, when I navigate to the `/test`, I see 404.

What do I miss here? Should I configure next.js 13 to recognize both `pages` and `app` directory?

**Update**:

In fact when I use `npx create-next-app site --use-npm` it does not have the `app` directory, though it's `13.0.0` in the `package.json`. And even there when I add a page inside `app/test/page.js`, I still get 404 when I navigate to `/test` directory.

Answer (score 2):

try to add `@latest` & `--experimental-app`

example:
`npx create-next-app@latest --experimental-app site`

You need to set `experimental.appDir` to enable app directory feature

```js
// next.config.js
const nextConfig = {
  experimental: {
    appDir: true,
  },
};
```

- true: **app** directory
- false: **pages** directory

#### Update:

- add `@latest`